# My UIAlertController keeps adding new buttons each time the alert is called, causing endless buttons

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uialertcontroller

I am adding alerts to prevent the user from overwriting previously used data, and I am using a UIAlertController as recommended in a different post. The involved code looks like this :

```
var alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "This will overwrite your information", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

func showAlert() {

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Overwrite", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Nevermind", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    }))

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    showAlert()
}
```

The first time it appears, it will be normal. The second time will show four buttons:

**Overwrite, Nevermind, Overwrite, Nevermind.**

The third time will show SIX buttons:

**Overwrite, Nevermind, Overwrite, Nevermind, Overwrite, Nevermind.**

And so on, forever. What is causing this and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Only use `alert.addAction...` once. Put it in the `viewDidLoad()` or something that is only called once. If you stop and think about what you're doing you are adding buttons every time you call show alert so naturally there will be more buttons each time. Either that, or create a new instance of alert each time you call the function.

Comment: You need to create a new alert controller inside the `showAlert` function.

Comment: Move the `alert` variable inside the `showAlert` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a variable `alert` which you instantiate somewhere in your code.
In your function `showAlert()` you add the actions (Overwrite, Nevermind) and you do this everytime you call that function.

Either move the instantiation of `alert` in `showAlert` or add the actions only once, where you instantiate `alert`.

```
func showAlert() {
    let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "This will overwrite your information", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Overwrite", style: .Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Nevermind", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

    }))

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Yep, makes perfect sense. Moved the instantiation into the function and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as correct by clicking on the hollow checkmark.

Comment: I know, you just answered too quickly for the website's likeness and I have to wait a few minutes, but I absolutely will!